# How can one pass a non-string parameter between page and master templates?

Tags: playframework, template-engine

This shouldn't work:

page:

```
#{extends 'master.html'/}
#{set parameter:foo.bar/} //foo is passed from contoller
```

master.html:

```
#{list items:parameter, as item}
 ... 
#{/list}
```

Is there any way to do this trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to play with this a bit, but the #{set} tag does not work well for lists.  Try this in your page (not master.html):

```
%{ parameter = foo.bar; }%
```

Hope that helps.