# Acquire Variables used from Parent Template in Play framework

Tags: playframework, extends

I want to use a variable which is used in main.html to all the child template.

For Ex,

I read a property called "ClientID" in main.html. This has to be used in all the inherited html templates instead of reading the same property once again. How to achive this in Play framework

Comment: with `%{ ClientID = ... }%`

the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055058/how-can-one-pass-a-non-string-parameter-between-page-and-master-templates

Comment: @sdespolit Actually I need the reverse. I define the variable in main.html. I will extend this template in child.html and need to get the value which is defined in main.html

Comment: i've got it, but haven't tested. it really doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to inject ClientID thro Controllers. But I needed that client ID in all the pages But I shouldn't keep in Session or Cookies. Thats why I wanted to get in main.html and use it in child templates. But I achived this in another way. Defined Play PlugIn, its like an ServletFilter. Overidden 'beforeActionInvocation' and injected the ClientID for all th requests

Answer (score 3):

In Groovy Templates, you have a predefined variable called "_caller" which allows to access the template's caller variables

```
${_caller.your_var}
```

Comment: It's not helping me. I checked with Play framework dcoumentation and it doesn't have any word called '_caller'. This what I have done, In main.html i defined the varialbe as %{clientID = "107"}% and retrieved the varialbe in child tempalte as ${_caller.clientID}. It throws me NPE. Please hrlp me to resolve this.

Comment: I think those local template variables are not bound in the _caller context as the variables coming from your controller. Can't your inject this clientId from the controller directly? _caller is not documented and I looked at Play code (GroovyTemplate class) directly to find it...

Comment: I was able to inject ClientID thro Controllers. But I needed that client ID in all the pages But I shouldn't keep in Session or Cookies. Thats          why I wanted to get in main.html and use it in child templates.                                                           But I achived this in another way. Defined Play PlugIn, its like an ServletFilter. Overidden 'beforeActionInvocation' and injected the ClientID for all th requests. Thanks for your support